# Designing a messaging server, with the ability to save data

Tags: algorithm, database-design

I'm developing an application like IRC chat with the ability to save data for later downloading them.
I would like to receive data in a certain period of time ...
How best to save data in the database, I do not understand. If I save the data every time I send a message, when I call the AddMessage () function, if the data is sent for example every millisecond, then my database will be overloaded (for example, the "INSERT" command will be sent to the database 1000 times.) I think that correctly store data when messages reach a certain limit, let's say if there are 500. But how true is this solution?
Here such I had a question in designing of application.
[image]

Comment: irc is the new wheel

Comment: Why not cache messages in memory and write the full cache to the DB when a memory or time threshold is crossed?

Answer (score 0):

The common way of doing this is via asynchronous designs. You're right - writing messages to your database at the time it's sent creates all sorts of scalability and performance challenges.

You don't mention your technology stack - so this will be inherently generic - but pretty much every major technology has a message queuing system available; NodeJS is explicitly written for asynchronous usage.

The way this typically works is that you have several asynchronous processes reading and writing to the message queue.

For instance:

Client 1 sends message to client 2.

```
Client1: put message "hello" to client2 on message bus
Client1: listen for messages on message bus...
Client2: listen for messages on message bus...
Client2: receive "hello" message from client1 on message bus
Client2: acknowledge receipt
```

At exactly the same time:

Database listener recording messages:

```
Database listener: listen for messages on the message bus
Database listener: see "hello" message from client1 to client2
Database listener: write "hello" message to database
Database listener: listen for messages on the message bus
Database listener: see acknowledgement from client2 on message bus
Database listener: mark "hello" message as received
```

[EDIT]

There are a number of popular message queuing systems; RabbitMQ (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39122247/why-do-you-need-a-message-queue-for-a-chat-with-web-sockets) question), [Apache RocketMQ](http://rocketmq.apache.org/) is another. The specific implementation would depend heavily on the overall architecture and messaging system you choose. The general ideas are explained in [Patterns of Enterprise Integration.](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Technology is not fundamental, I'm still designing. I did not quite understand, in your example it turns out that the record in the database will occur in a separate thread, this thread will read the queue and write to the database? Can you give an example of implementation?

Comment: If you use an on-the-shelf technology for the message queue, you could as well use any irc server / irc proxy like [bip](https://www.irc.wiki/BIP) directly.